# Java's Serial garbage collector performing far better than other garbage collectors?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm testing an API, written in Java, that is expected to minimize latency in processing messages received over a network.  To achieve these goals, I'm playing around with the different garbage collectors that are available.

I'm trying four different techniques, which utilize the following flags to control garbage collection:

1) Serial: -XX:+UseSerialGC

2) Parallel: -XX:+UseParallelOldGC

3) Concurrent: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

4) Concurrent/incremental: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing

I ran each technique over the course of five hours.  I periodically used the list of GarbageCollectorMXBean provided by ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans() to retrieve the total time spent collecting garbage.

My results?  Note that "latency" here is "Amount of time that my application+the API spent processing each message plucked off the network."

Serial: 789 GC events totaling 1309 ms; mean latency 47.45 us, median latency 8.704 us, max latency 1197 us

Parallel: 1715 GC events totaling 122518 ms; mean latency 450.8 us, median latency 8.448 us, max latency 8292 us

Concurrent: 4629 GC events totaling 116229 ms; mean latency 707.2 us, median latency 9.216 us, max latency 9151 us

Incremental: 5066 GC events totaling 200213 ms; mean latency 515.9 us, median latency 9.472 us, max latency 14209 us

I find these results to be so improbable that they border on absurd.  Does anyone know why I might be having these kinds of results?

Oh, and for the record, I'm using Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM.

Comment: Are you assuming that executing two things in parallel is necessarily faster than executing one thing after another?

Comment: I would expect the maximum latency to go up though

Comment: So, how many messages were actually processed in those 5 hours in your different scenarios? Are you running a single thread, or multithreaded?

Comment: I processed 431.8 million messages each time.  The application uses two threads -- one on the critical path grabs the messages off the wire and packs them into a queue.  The one on the non-critical path takes them out of the queue and places them in a priority queue; then, once a second, it drains the priority queue and calculates median/mean/max/etc latency statistics for that second.  This machine has two 6-core Intel Xeon 5680s and 24 GB RAM.

Answer (score 19):

> I'm working on a Java application that is expected to maximize throughput and minimize latency

Two problems with that:

- Those are often contradictory goals, so you need to decide *how* important each is against the other (would you sacrifice 10% latency to get 20% throughput gain or vice versa? Are you aiming for some *specific* latency target, beyond which it doesn't matter whether it's any faster? Things like that.)
- Your haven't given any results around *either* of these

All you've shown is how much time is spent in the garbage collector. If you *actually* achieve more throughput, you would probably *expect* to see more time spent in the garbage collector. Or to put it another way, I can make a change in the code to minimize the values you're reporting really easily:

```
// Avoid generating any garbage
Thread.sleep(10000000);
```

You need to work out what's *actually* important to you. Measure everything that's important, then work out where the trade-off lies. So the *first* thing to do is re-run your tests and measure latency and throughput. You may *also* care about total CPU usage (which isn't the same as CPU in GC of course) but while you're not measuring your primary aims, your results aren't giving you particularly useful information.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I wish I could give an extra +1 for your solution to avoid generating garbage :-)

Comment: Three things.  First, I understand that the goals are often contradictory.  I suppose "latency" would be my primary goal.  Second, I'm not just iterating through a file or something.  The applications are processing network traffic (same set of traffic for every run of the application), so the amount of data being processed is the same over every run.  Third, I will post my latency results in my main post in a moment.

Comment: the user asked a fair question, with specific data, doing his best. sorry Jon, for me is a downvote for you, this answer is too generic and really doesn't give any insight neither direction to the user and all the readers.

Comment: @Massimo: It may be worth noting that the latency data was added after I'd answered the question. It originally only included the GC timing. I'm not asking you to remove your downvote, nor am I going to take pains to edit a 6 year old answer though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't find this surprising at all.

The problem with serial garbage collection is that while it's running, nothing else can run at all (aka "stops the world"). That has a good point though: it keeps the amount of work spent on garbage collection to just about its bare minimum.

Almost any sort of parallel or concurrent garbage collection has to do a fair amount of extra work to ensure that all modifications to the heap appear atomic to the rest of the code. Instead of just stopping everything for a while, it has to stop *just* those things that depend on a particular change, and then for just long enough to carry out that specific change. It then lets that code start running again, gets to the next point that it's going to make a change, stops other pieces of code that depend on it, and so on.

The other point (though in this case, probably a fairly minor one) is that as you process more data, you generally expect to generate more garbage, and therefore spend more time doing garbage collection. Since the serial collector does stop all other processing while it does its job, that not only makes the garbage collection fast, but also prevents any more garbage from being generated during that time.

Now, why do I say that's probably a minor contributor in this case? That's pretty simple: the serial collector only used up a little over a second out of five hours. Even though nothing else got done during that ~1.3 seconds, that's such a small percentage of five hours that it probably didn't make any much (if any) real difference to your overall throughput.

Summary: the problem with serial garbage collection isn't that it uses excessive time overall -- it's that it can be very inconvenient if it stops the world right when you happen to need fast response. At the same time, I should add that as long as your collection cycles are short, this can still be fairly minimal. In theory, the other forms of GC mostly limit your worst case, but in fact (e.g., by limiting the heap size) you can often limit your maximum latency with a serial collector as well.

Answer (score 2):

There was an excellent talk by a Twitter engineer at the 2012 [QCon Conference](http://qconlondon.com/) on this topic - you can watch it [here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/JVM-Performance-Tuning-twitter-QCon-London-2012).

It discussed the various "generations" in the Hotspot JVM memory and garbage collection (Eden, Survivor, Old). In particular note that the "Concurrent" in ConcurrentMarkAndSweep only applies to the Old generation, i.e. objects that hang around for a while.

Short-lived objects are GCd from the "Eden" generation - this is cheap, but is a "stop-the-world" GC event regardless of which GC algorithm you have chosen!

The advice was to tune the young generation first e.g. allocate lots of new Eden so there's more chance for objects to die young and be reclaimed cheaply. Use +PrintGCDetails, +PrintHeapAtGC, +PrintTenuringDistribution... If you get more than 100% survivor then there wasn't room, so objects get quickly promoted to Old - this is Bad.

When tuning for the Old generatiohn, if latency is top priority, it was recommended to try ParallelOld with auto-tune first (+AdaptiveSizePolicy etc), then try CMS, then maybe the new G1GC.

Comment: The slides are also available at http://www.slideshare.net/aszegedi/everything-i-ever-learned-about-jvm-performance-tuning-twitter, if the link above is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks - I've also updated the link in my answer to point to the new location of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can not say one GC is better than the other. it depends on your requirements and your application.

but if u want to maximize throughput and minimize latency: GC is your enemy! you should not call GC at all and also try to prevent JVM from calling GC.

go with serial and use object pools.

Answer (score 0):

With serial collection, only one thing happens at a time. For example, even when multiple CPUs are
available, only one is utilized to perform the collection. When parallel collection is used, the task of
garbage collection is split into parts and those subparts are executed simultaneously, on different
CPUs. The simultaneous operation enables the collection to be done more quickly, at the expense of
some additional complexity and potential fragmentation.

While the serial GC uses only one thread to process a GC, the parallel GC uses several threads to process a GC, and therefore, faster. This GC is useful when there is enough memory and a large number of cores. It is also called the **"throughput GC."**